# Can't install psycopg2 (Python2.6 Ubuntu9.10 PostgreSQL8.4.2)

Tags: postgresql, installation, ubuntu-9.10, psycopg2

```
~/psycopg2-2.0.13$ python setup.py install

running install

running build

running build_py

creating build

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/psycopg2

copying lib/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/psycopg2

copying lib/pool.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/psycopg2

copying lib/extensions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/psycopg2

copying lib/errorcodes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/psycopg2

copying lib/extras.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/psycopg2

copying lib/tz.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/psycopg2

copying lib/psycopg1.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/psycopg2

running build_ext

**error: No such file or directory**
```

or

```
$ sudo easy_install psycopg2==2.0.13

Searching for psycopg2==2.0.13

Reading http;//pypi.python.org/simple/psycopg2/

Reading http;//initd.org/projects/psycopg2

Reading http;//initd.org/pub/software/psycopg/

Best match: psycopg2 2.0.13

Downloading http;//initd.org/pub/software/psycopg/psycopg2-2.0.13.tar.gz

Processing psycopg2-2.0.13.tar.gz

Running psycopg2-2.0.13/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-QuViWt/psycopg2-2.0.13/egg-dist-tmp-P2W9Dh

error: Setup script exited with error: No such file or directory
```

Comment: sudo apt-get install python-psycopg2 
thanks

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the fact that on Bubuntu you can always install psycopg from a .deb package you're probably missing PostgreSQL development headers and the pg_config command. Try installing libpq-dev and maybe also one of the postgresql-sever-dev-X.Y packages. Also, psycopg 2.0.13 is quite old: using a new version would have given a better looking error message.